# correct English pronunciation of the word poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, pronunciation

What is the correct English pronunciation of the word poset (Partially Ordered SET)?

paazit or pow-set?

Comment: Some of us usually pronounce it *partially ordered set* or *partial order*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither...I would probably transliterate it as "poh-set". You definitely want to pronounce "set" as it's own syllable.

"Poh" rhymes with though, row, snow, toe, etc.

Comment: *row* suggest more than one possibility and may rhyme with *pow*

Comment: Good point. I have a bit of an accent and didn't think of that when I was trying to come up with rhyming words. Hopefully the OP understands my intent.

Answer (score 7):

PO-set.

"PO" rhymes with "snow".

At least in my neck of the woods...

Answer (score 4):

Poset rhymes with LOW-SET or ROW-SET. Similarly for woset (well-ordered set). Watch this YouTube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DQcTbN0eeY) where Doctor Bob says POSET around 7:50.

Comment: *row* suggest more than one possibility

Comment: @Henry I added a link to a video to avoid confusion.